# can we use javafx instead of swing for developing desktop application?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am trying to develop the desktop application using java fx instead of java swing will it be a good idea? does java fx supports database functions ? please help me out with your answers guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can. Since everything you did to communicate with a database in swing will also work in javafx. This is because neither of them supports database communication by default. Therefore you will have to use a database library like hibernate. But I guess you already did that for swing. 
Swing AND JavaFX are GUI-Libraries and nothing else. Any additional library functionality MUST be provided by another library for BOTH of them.

Hope this was of help :)

Comment: yeah am clear now thank u :)